# Metadata exporting and editing options in Soundminer HD and HD Plus

Tags: metadata, soundminer

Anyone know if Soundminer HD Plus allows you to export the metadata of your effects library to a text/excell file?

I currently have Soundminer HD and am not able to do it, apparently the option should be under Database/Dump Query to Text File.

I was thinking of updating, however the Product Comparison on the soundminer web page is a bit vague when it comes to the differences between metadata editing options (in that it doesn't mention exporting metadata text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is actually in a different area (and labeled differently) in Windows.

Go to Edit/Dump Results to Text.

I should clarify I'm basing this on HD Plus. Not sure if it is in plain HD.

Comment: Ah thanks.  Unfortunately I also already upgraded to HD Plus as well, so I can no longer check if basic HD has this option either.  If anyone has soundminer HD on windows and can check that would be awesome.